# Rails3+CSV wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) , in generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In development mode iam using (rails3 and ruby 1.9.2p136) and CSV is working good,

but,

In production mode iam using (rails3 and ruby 1.9.2p0) and CSV throws error

(wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) , in generate)

please can u suggest me what could be the problem.

thanks

Comment: Can you add the line of code that is throwing the error and possibly a stack trace?

Comment: Which gem you are using to generate the CSV . Please check the gem version of on both environment and try to lock the gems . As sometime  different gem version may cause this types of problem . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exact same problem on Fedora15 with ruby 1.8.7 .
Code below fixed the CSV.generate problem.

```
if RUBY_VERSION < "1.9" 
require "rubygems" 
require "faster_csv" 
CSV = FCSV 
else 
require "csv"
end
```